# Can permission inheritance be broken and new permission be given at column level in sharepoint 2013 ?

Tags: 2013, site-column, app-permissions

Can permission inheritance be broken and new permission be given at column level ? If yes , can we do it from UI ? 
Can we do it from code?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but there is no version of SharePoint provides column level permission management out of the box.

As a workaround, there will be many third party plugins/tools to achieve this. This one is from codeplex, you can follow the url. http://spcolumnpermission.codeplex.com/

Another alternative (also my preferred way) is to, add a script editor web part on page, write the script to hide columns you required based on IDs. And finally set the target audience for the script editor web part to the group or person from whom you want to hide.

Comment: So the last option of writing the script can be considered as coding option?? I mean it is achievable by CSOM/JSOM?

Comment: I am not aware of how these third party tools are working. So cant justify if it can done or not by using CSOM or JSOM. Also the 2nd option I had provided is much more simpler than CSOM or JSOM. You need to have basic JS skills to show/hide DOM element. Rest its SharePoint doing Audience targeting.